# Android - Text on Button

Tags: java, android

I need to show the **text on button's both left & right side**, whenever I touch the left side that should call an intent , and when I touch the right side that should call a separate intent . Is it possible to do like that? Please anyone suggest me.

Comment: Why don't you use two buttons instead?

Comment: no , i can't , there shud be  only one button which shud have texts on both sides

Answer (score 4):

```
<LinearLayout
android:background="button's">

<TextView
android:id = "@+id/left"
android:clickable="true"
android:text="left"
/>

<TextView
android:id = "@+id/right"
android:clickable="true"
android:text="right"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and at run time.. do 2 diff things when those two Text views are clicked...

this will have similar effect...